# Factory creating two different objects at the same time

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory

If I had a program for a 2 player game that took user input and based on that input, used a factory pattern to create a new a player1 and then took more input and created a new player2. If I was to assume that player1 was always going to be the user i.e no Computer v Computer games. Can I the input to one, ask for a type of opponent, and create both players at the same time? The code works for me, but am I violating anything that I shouldn't be by doing this?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PlayerFactory {

   public List<Abstract_Player> makePlayerType(String playerType){
       if(playerType.equals("2")){
         List<Abstract_Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Abstract_Player>();
         playerList.add(new Player1());
         playerList.add(new Player2());
         return playerList;
      } else if(playerType.equals("c")){
         List<Abstract_Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Abstract_Player>();
         playerList.add(new Player1());
         playerList.add(new Computer());
         return playerList;
      }
      return null;
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking if it's problem that your Factory is returning different objects based on input to it, then no, that's exactly what a Factory pattern is supposed to do.

You are, however, making it do more than it needs to by making it create a player list instead of a player type.  I'd recommend making the player factory do one thing - create players. Then the code that uses it can create the list.  This follows the goal of a [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) for the factory, and reduces the total amount of code you need.  Example code below.

**PlayerFactory**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class PlayerFactory {

   public Abstract_Player makePlayerType(String playerType){
       if(playerType.equals("2")){
         return new Player2();
      } else if(playerType.equals("c")){
         List<Abstract_Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Abstract_Player>();
         return new Computer();
      }
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown player type " + playerType);
   }
}
```

**Code using player factory**

```
List<Abstract_Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Abstract_Player>();
playerList.add(new Player1());
Abstract_Player opponent = playerFactory.makePlayerType(playerType);
playerlist.add(opponent);
```